# Self referencing model in EF Code First 4.1 throws 'Collection was modified' exception

Tags: ef-code-first

I am trying to model the following using EF 4.1 and cannot get past this exception ("Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute").

Models:

```
public class Workflow
{
    public List<WorkflowStage> Stages { get; set; }
}

public class WorkflowStage
{
    public virtual List<WorkflowNextStage> WorkflowNextStages { get; set; }
}

public abstract class WorkflowNextStage
{
    public virtual WorkflowStage NextStage { get; set; }
}

public class SuccessStage : WorkflowNextStage
{
}

public class FailureStage : WorkflowNextStage
{
}
```

Configuration:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowStage>()
            .HasMany(x => x.WorkflowNextStages)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("CurrentStageId"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowNextStage>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.NextStage)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("NextStageId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Failing code:

```
    using (var ctx = new SBContext())
        {
            var workflow = new Workflow();
            var stage = new WorkflowStage();
            stage.WorkflowNextStages = new List<WorkflowNextStage>
                                           {
                                               new SuccessStage() {NextStage = stage},
                                               new FailureStage() {NextStage = stage}
                                           };

            workflow.Stages = new List<WorkflowStage> {stage};

            ctx.Workflows.Add(workflow);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Setting the 'new SuccessStage' above to a different stage works just fine.

I am a bit stumped on this one...anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Would love to help, please paste the entire stack trace as it may be helpful here.  What is the whole error you receive and at what line is it breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a foreach loop where you are iterating through the collection you are modifying?  If so this may cause this error.